# Specify foreign key constraint name when using Map and @ElementCollection with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have a sort of exotic mapping for a field:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "studentGradeLevel", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "studentId"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "schoolYearId")
@Column(name = "gradeLevel", nullable = false)
@ForeignKey(name = "fkStudentGrade2Student")
private Map<SchoolYear, GradeLevel> gradeLevels;
```

SchoolYear is an entity and GradeLevel is an enum.

I am using Hibernate tools to generate the DDL for the schema.  The schema that this generates is below:

```
create table studentGradeLevel (
    studentId numeric(19,0) not null,
    gradeLevel int not null,
    schoolYearId int not null,
    primary key (studentId, schoolYearId)
);

alter table studentGradeLevel 
    add constraint FK1BCA4A883A97C498 
    foreign key (schoolYearId) 
    references schoolYear;

alter table studentGradeLevel 
    add constraint fkStudentGrade2Student 
    foreign key (studentId) 
    references student;
```

The problem is that I can't seem to change the constraint name for the foreign key between the collection table and the table for the entity used as the map key.

I've used @ForeignKey to specify constraint names for @OneToMany, @ManyToMany and other @ElementCollections with no problem.  I've tried @ForiegnKey's "inverseName" attribute but it seems to be ignored. @MapKeyJoinColumn doesn't appear to have any properties that would affect this.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: You mean 'FK1BCA4A883A97C498' ?  Why do you want to manage the name of this.

Comment: Yes. The reason is so that if the constraint is violated the error that is returned will contain a meaningful name.

Comment: Someone opened a ticket right here: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HCANN-24 . You might want to vote that up so that the Hibernate developers know the importance to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, that's an issue similar to mine but not exactly the same. Maybe I can piggyback off it.

Comment: Yea, I doubt using `ImprovedNamingStrategy` helps in your case, because all it does is to remove the camel casing by placing underscores, which doesn't solve your problem: http://almaer.com/blog/hibernate-improvednamingstrategy

Comment: @Cliff - ah yes.  Makes sense.   Don't know answer however can highly recommend 'Pro JPA2' (Apress).  I am studying the map section currently.  As suggested worth trawling JIRA or pose Q via Hibernate forum ?

Comment: I wouldn't count on automatic schema generation for anything important. You'll have to specify table spaces, checked constraints, indices and all kinds of things anyway. Use dedicated hand-written scripts, with comments inside.

Comment: @Nizet absolutely but it's a very useful starting point to be able to work off the generated script for schemas with hundreds of tables.

Answer (score 6):

I had to patch Hibernate to create different foreign key names, because the ones Hibernate created for me weren't really useful.

I took the Hibernate source, and placed the Source of the class `org.hibernate.mapping.Table` into my source folder, which is a the start of the classpath (the resulting jar in my project starts with a letter lower than the hibernate.jar, so this even works in webapps).

The I replaced the function uniqueColumnString with the following code (Original code at the top of the function):

```
    public String uniqueColumnString(Iterator iterator, String referencedEntityName) {
//        int result = 0;
//        if ( referencedEntityName != null ) {
//            result += referencedEntityName.hashCode();
//        }
//        while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
//            result += iterator.next().hashCode();
//        }
//        return ( Integer.toHexString( name.hashCode() ) + Integer.toHexString( result ) ).toUpperCase();
          StringBuilder retVal = new StringBuilder();
          retVal.append("_").append(referencedEntityName);
          while( iterator.hasNext() ) {
              Column c = (Column)iterator.next();
              retVal.append("_");
              retVal.append(c.getName());
          }
          return retVal.toString();
    }
```

This returns automatically nice strings like "_Entity_attributeName_id", which will be used to create foreign keys like "fk_Entity_attributeName_id"! Never have to specify my names by hand again :)))

Comment: This is a great idea and I will try it out.

Comment: Please tell me how it worked out! I did never try this on an ElementCollection! And IMHO my solution is even better that hibernates in terms of uniqueness. Their solution could generate duplicate values, while mine is always unique (at least as long as it stays below the identifier length limit of the Dialect).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and because I couldn't find a way to do it ended up querying the database itself to get that information.

Running this query on SQL SERVER

```
select kcu.TABLE_NAME, kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, kcu.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as tc
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE as kcu
on kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
and kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME  = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
and kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA    = tc.TABLE_SCHEMA
and kcu.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME
```

You will get tablename, constraint name (like FK1BCA4A883A97C498), type (like UNIQUE constraint) and column name.
That should be enought to return a meaningful error message.

I know is not great because you loose the db portability but apparently there is no way to do what you are asking for at the moment...